# How to make an Ajax loader follow mouse?

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, ajax, dhtml

I want to have something on my site that follows the mouse around, sort of like how Windows 7 does it.

Like in Windows 7 when something is loading up a little circle comes and follows the mouse.

I am using the jQuery library so I know I can use Ajax Start and Stop to make it appear but am not sure how to make it follow the mouse around.

Any plugins to do this or how to do this?

Comment: For those who aren't blessed with Windows 7, can you explain what behaviour you want with a video or something?

Comment: I think he just wants something like the old school spinning hour glass + cursor.

Comment: Forget the circle.  Just make it a flock of birds.  That would be really cool.

Comment: I think you may be misusing the term AJAX. AJAX refers to the method of communication with the server achieved with javascript, nothing to do with things that are happening on the screen, what you may be describing is DHTML.

Comment: @Roberto, I think he means the usual `loading.gif` image that some pages use when Ajax content is being retrieved from the server, between the `onClick` and the `append()`.

Comment: @Roberto No I am not missing using the term AJAX. I guess I could have rephrased my title a bit better. When I do a post/get with jquery ajax I have an option to set an AjaxStart and AjaxStop that does something while a AjaxStart request has been initiated like tell the user what is going on(ie loading). This is where I want to put a loading icon up but I want it to follow the mouse since this will make it so I can use it across pages and website since I don't have to worry about positioning.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.. OK I will re-tag it with AJAX then.. :)

Comment: @Jed Smith

I don't know what the 90s trend is but I think it is different then what I am talking about since alot of people sites use ajaxloader images I just want it attached to a mouse curosr then some place on my page.

Comment: @chobo2 Just as a side note though, you may want to think about disabling clicks while something is loading?  Because if you don't have a loader screen to block clicks the user might still go click crazy even though the mouse pointer is indicating that something is loading.

Comment: Yep good point was already thinking about that since when doing my own things and having no loader I clicked my button multiple times doing multiple requests to the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the cursor instead to one of the standard OS "wait" cursors.  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html has a good grid of options and browser compatibilities.  Hover over the cursor name in the grid to see an example in your browser.

It looks like you might want the progress cursor.

```
mystyle { cursor: progress; }
```

Comment: Ya this seems pretty good expect since I can do like said above and put it in the body tag. It looks how I wanted it too look.

Only thing I don't like is that if you hover over like textboxes it goes away.

Answer (score 6):

That question was already answered here: [jQuery tooltip follow mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279254/jquery-tooltip-follow-mouse)

However, that solution may slow down users' browsers due to the amount of calculations made during that proccess. I'd recommend you to change the browser's cursor using this trick in CSS:

```
cursor : url("custom.cur");
```

Comment: Hmm the cursor:progress is what I was thinking of but I am unsure how to make it run always. Like I looked at w3cschools and they have it like when you hover over a word.

Comment: @chobo2, Apply it to `*` or `body`?

Comment: how could I add something to the body with jquery?

Comment: ah what am I thinking lol. It just a html tag that I probably can add the style too.

Comment: hmm that might work the only thing I don't like is when you go over a box or something it goes back to default cursor. I would like it to take over all of them while it is running.

Comment: You can either use document.body.style.cursor = 'system_cursor_name', or apply it via jquery, like $('body').css('cursor', 'url(custom.cur)');

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd add a bit to this answer. My addition to the answer doesn't actually cover how to use JQuery to do this. Instead it covers how to use the ASP.NET Ajax Framework. This framework is automatically part of the page if your page (or MasterPage) has a ScriptManager on it. This framework is the one that's used by UpdatePanels and other Ajax Server controls in order to work.

The [PageRequestManager Class](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/default.aspx) manages partial-page updates (ajax requests). You can use this class to implement methods that should be executed whenever something to do with an ajax request occurs (like an ajax request begins or ends, or if an error has occurred while making the ajax request).

So, to implement this solution using the Ajax.NET framework instead of JQuery, grab a reference to the PageRequestManager and implement methods that will executed during the PageRequestManager's beginRequest and endRequest events to change the cursor style for the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(endRequestEventHandler);
    prm.add_beginRequest(beginRequestEventHandler);

    function beginRequestEventHandler() {
        var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        bodyElement.style.cursor = "wait";
    }
    function endRequestEventHandler() {
        var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        bodyElement.style.cursor = "default";
    }    
</script>
```

It's pretty simple. When the page is making an Ajax request to the server the PageRequestManager's "beginRequest" event occurs and your method changes the cursor to a "wait" cursor (by default I think it's the circle thing in Vista but I'm not sure and can't test it because I'm working with XP right now).

When the Ajax request returns to the browser the PageRequestManager's endRequest event occurs and your method changes the cursor back to "default".

The only thing that the user will have to do in order to see this cursor change is move the mouse a bit (then the style's applied). At least I noticed this behaviour in FireFox when I tested the above code.

Happy coding

-Frinny

Answer (score 1):

I would rather do it more elegantly like so:

```
$(function(){  
  $("html").bind("ajaxStart", function(){  
     $(this).addClass('busy');  
   }).bind("ajaxStop", function(){  
     $(this).removeClass('busy');  
   });  
});
```

CSS:

```
html.busy, html.busy * {  
  cursor: wait !important;  
}
```

Source: http://postpostmodern.com/instructional/global-ajax-cursor-change/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean mouse trails?

If so, you can do it via DHTML. [Click Here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/trailer.htm) for a good example with code.

Comment: Ya basically just a jquery solution. I am pretty sure it has stuff available to do this.